# Float to Right?

Tags: css

This is a slightly confusing question to ask, but interesting nonetheless.

Basically, I am working on an animated bouncer on the side of a webpage, sort of like what is found on normal music players. The animation is fine, but I want to float the animated divs to the right without floating. If the divs are floated to the right, they display how I want them. However, when the width becomes small, they append onto the same line and seem to "twitch" and disappear.

So I'm looking for a way to float these guys to the right without causing them to end up on the same line. I haven't yet been able to find anything that doesn't end up with position fixed or absolute (which does not work for the overall layout and causes a bevy of other problems).

The snippet below is with float right to show the "twitching" behavior.

```css
@keyframes lineBounce1 {
 to {
  width:60%;
 }
 from {
  width:10%;
 }
}

@keyframes lineBounce2 {
 to {
  width:80%;
 }
 from {
  width:30%;
 }
}

.playlist{
 display:inline-block;
 position:absolute;
 height:70%;
 width:30%;
 left:27%;
 top:7%;
 text-align:center;
 min-height:300px;
 min-width:400px;
 background-color:white;
 overflow-y:auto;
 overflow-x:hidden;
}

.playhead {
 height:20%;
 width:100%;
}

.bounce {
 height:100%;
 width:20%;
 float:right;
}

.lineDance1 {
 display:block;
    float:right;
 margin-top:5px;
 height:5%;
 background-color:rgb(153, 000, 000);
 animation-direction:alternate;
 animation-duration:500ms;
 animation-iteration-count:infinite;
 animation-name:lineBounce1;
}

.lineDance2 {
 display:block;
    float:right;
 margin-top:5px;
 height:5%;
 background-color:rgb(153, 000, 000);
 animation-direction:alternate;
 animation-duration:750ms;
 animation-iteration-count:infinite;
 animation-name:lineBounce2;
}
```

```html
<span class="playlist">
  <div class="playhead">
   <span>
   </span>
   <span class="bounce">
    <div class="lineDance1"></div>
    <div class="lineDance2"></div>
   </span>
  </div>
  <div id="playlist">
  </div>
 </span>
```

EDIT: Just clarifying, since I don't think I was totally clear...

I want them to begin on the right side of the playlist and "bounce" (expand) towards the left. Currently they are on the left-hand side of the span and "bounce" (expand) towards the right.

Comment: good way to express your problem is to use "code snippet tool"

Comment: <span> is an inline element and <div> is a block element, so in terms of HTML validation, you can't put block elements inside inline elements - http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/struct/global.html#h-7.5.4

Comment: Your link does not appear to work, @ASR Looked it up via Google, my bad. I'm self-taught when it comes to web coding so I tend towards the "what works" vs "what is actually good practice" most of the time. Thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what I need to do for this!

I ended up displaying the container as a flex and aligning it to the flex end. This will yield you the desired results for anyone else with this issue.

[Here is a related article on align properties.](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_align-items.asp)